# How do I search for a five digit number in a string column?

Tags: sql, string, wildcard, numeric, teradata

What I'm trying to do is determine (Using Teradata SQL) if a person's zip code has accidently been put on an address line. I've looked on various forums and I can't find any similar questions.

Ultimately, I would want to write something like:

```
Where address_line_1 like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Any ideas?

Target database is Teradata 13.x

Comment: Which version of Teradata are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to inspect the entire column to see if it contains only a ZIP code, you might try something like this:

```
where address_line_1 between '00000' and '99999'
```

But if you are thinking of searching the entire string for any occurrence of five consecutive digits, that would not be a good test anyway.  For example, the following would be a perfectly valid mailing address:

```
28305 Southwest Main Street
```

Doing validity checks after data has been loaded is difficult; such a task should really be performed during the load process.

Comment: Have to agree that using a tool such as PostalSoft (now part of IBM's Data Quality Stack, if I recall correctly) to cleanse your addresses before loading them would be a more appropriate task. Otherwise, you are faced with the dilemma of "garbage in, garbage out".

Answer (score 1):

Find all the entries that match this regex `[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]`

As this will find numbers in some text that are exactly 5 digits long, assuming that's the definition of a zipcode.

Comment: Teradata does not support regex expressions until Teradata 14. OP did not indicate which version of Teradata they are using.

Comment: Wouldn't you know it, Version 13.

Comment: @ape Had there been regex support, Then also this regex would only return those entries where there would have existed non numeric values at extremes of a 5 digit string. example, it will match 'p12345q', but would fail for '12345'. Perhaps you meant to write, `[^0-9]?[0-9]{5}[^0-9]?`

Comment: This answer helped me on SQL Server. +1

Answer (score 0):

where address_line_1 between '00000' and '99999' would not work if there are four-digit numbers in your address_line_1 because it will pick them up
Where address_line_1 like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' would be a better solution.

Comment: [answer], [tour], https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help are recommended reads for you.

Comment: It looks like this is in response to another answer - please post this as a comment on that answer, instead of as a separate answer.